# Pop up for features inside a GeoJson File

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I uploaded a GeoJson file into GMaps API that has many polygon features in it, and now I'd like to create a pop up for each polygon. The content will be obtained from the attribute table of the GeoJson file from a field called "NAME".

Do you have a hint how to do that?[image]

Comment: Use a click listener and retrieve the data of that polygon to set the content of the infowindow. Have a look at this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814197/creating-infowindows-on-features-loaded-via-loadgeojson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a follow up answer. 
The quick way to do it is to use a listener event and extract values for each polygon using

```
event.feature.H.ATTRIBUTE_FIELD;
```

So, in my case it  ended up as the following?

```
Cities.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var str = event.feature.H.NAME;
    infowindow.setContent(str);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.LatLng());
    infowindow.open(map);
});
```